# Capacitance multiplier for synth PSU?

Tags: power-supply, power-filtering

Noob alert.

I'm about to build a pretty simple PSU for my modular synth project. I'm looking at a few schematics from popular sites and I've previously built a simple wall-wart one based on [this from MusicFromOuterSpace](http://musicfromouterspace.com/index.php?MAINTAB=SYNTHDIY%20using%20LM7912%20and%20LM7812).

[image: Schematic]

There are also lots of kits with these 7812/7912 pairs like [this](https://www.banggood.com/DIY-LM7812LM7912-Dual-Voltage-Regulator-Rectifier-Bridge-Power-Supply-Module-5V-12V-Kit-p-1363569.html?gmcCountry=SE&currency=SEK&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_union&utm_content=2zou&utm_campaign=pla-all2-se-en-pc&gclid=Cj0KCQiArqPgBRCRARIsAPwlHoXE9RgOOi3wlJ44WgDhjwz376YPlV3aI21Tsu0PF-d2THapEru2bzUaAqCAEALw_wcB&ID=557391&cur_warehouse=CN).

But then I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wopmEyZKnYo) on capacitance multipliers and just don't understand why this isn't used everywhere? I guess I'm missing something.

What I mean is, it seems to be a really *big thing* to really reduce ripple on power for synth applications. The schematics I'm looking at are sticking really really big electrolytics in there to do that - it's like that's probably the big material cost for these PSU's. Like 10kuF or so. Wouldn't it be a very simple win to just use a mosfet capacitance multiplier just before the voltage regulator?

Comment: Your schematic shows single-diode (half-wave) rectifier. That gives 50/60 Hz ripple. You can reduce ripple by **half** with full-wave rectifier (the extra diode(s) are cheaper than monster electrolytics)...you now have 100/120 Hz ripple. Mind you, for audio work, some may complain that 50/60 Hz is less objectionable than 100/120 Hz, if it gets into the audio signal path.

Comment: yes, sure, this was just because it was a simple ac/ac wall-wart supply with dual rail output. you'd need center-tapped transformer for full-wave dual rail output, right?

Comment: A 12V RMS centre-tapped transformer (with 2 diodes) works. But the whole idea of reducing ripple *going into the regulator* seems like a pedantic notion...groundloop currents may have a bigger impact on audible hum.

Comment: The point he is making in the video about here https://youtu.be/wopmEyZKnYo?t=286 is that regulators are really not very good at mitigating ripple from the input. But I guess this is all about higher frequencies on switched supplies, not mains ripple…

Comment: Hi Viktor. When you have URL links, you can embed them in your question instead of pasting a giant link to detract from the question. See my edit to see how (or use the "link" button (that looks like a chain) when composing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A capacitance multiplier can mimic a capacitor of large value but it can't hold-up the supply voltage from a bridge rectifier because it doesn't store the energy that can be released to the load when the AC voltage drops to zero every 8 to 10 milliseconds. There are no free meals in electronics.

Comment: Oh, ok. So this would be more usable for a switching power supply?

Comment: No, because (1) switching power supplies don't require a lot of smoothing capacitance due to their high operating frequency and (2) adding a pass transistor to facilitate a capacitance multiplier means input to output voltage differential just like a linear regulator and hence power loss (so why use a switcher if you are going to add-back power loss using a linear circuit?).